# Remove /index.php from Permalink

Tags: permalinks

I have the problem that the my wordpress page permalink is not working without /index.php/%postname%/. If I remove it it says "Page not found". Can you please help me.

P.S. mod_rewrite is enabled

Answer (score 0):

`index.php`p is the main template file of the WordPress Theme. But without `index.php` will be active your theme but not work any functionality. So, if you want to active/work WordPress functionality then you must have `index.php` on your theme, otherwise it will break everything.

Q: Why you need to remove `index.php` file ?

See here https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: I need to remove it, because it is not working well with WooCommerce. If I am for example in the checkout basket and click on something from the menu it just gives me a URL withour index.php. Thats why I need to remove it